# NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.ldap.LdapName is a restricted class in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, plivo

We have `Goole App Engine` Java Project that uses `Plivo`(SMS, Phone Call Platform) to send SMS. It uses **[Plivo Java Library](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-java/)** to send a SMS. When I tried to send a sms, i got `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.naming.ldap.LdapName is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.extractCNs(AbstractVerifier.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.getCNs(AbstractVerifier.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLSocketFactory.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:536)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.plivo.helper.api.client.RestAPI.request(RestAPI.java:106)
```

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sms/twilio

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, App Engine runs in a sandboxed environment, so certain classes are unavailable.  The [whitelist](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) page will tell you which classes you can use.

If you need to make use of this specific third party library, you can either run the relevant part(s) of your app on Compute Engine, or look at [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/), which don't have the same restrictions as regular Java modules on App Engine.  The downside is that you don't enjoy the same auto-scaling characteristics and Managed VMs are still in preview.

Comment: When i check plivo java library, it is nowhere depends on LDAP package. Why it happens to third party library?

Comment: Your library is dependent on the Apache HTTP library referenced in the call stack, which in turn is dependent on LdapName (see [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-commits/201407.mbox/%3C20140728155736.AA8C62388A9B@eris.apache.org%3E) for example).

Comment: Okay. now i understood.